Linux From Scratch 12.1 GCC testsuite failing and timing out
I'm currently building Linux From Scratch 12.1 with the book, I've followed the instructions line by line. I'm struggling with the GCC testsuite, I have lots of FAIL and timeout. In addition to that, I'm running a Lubuntu VM with an LFS.vdi where I'm building LFS, during the test it is being filled to the point where the tests can't continue.
My VM runs lubuntu 64bit with 4proc and 10Gb RAM.
I have a 30Go drive dedicated to LFS.
I've tried this for the "not enough space" problem but it didn't work:
https://superuser.com/questions/529149/how-to-compact-virtualboxs-vdi-file-size
I don't really know where to look, any help would be greatly appreciated. If I can access some helpful logs, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Can you extend the size of the VDI to say 300GB?  That's 10x the size now?  I think you're running out of diskspace for the compile to complete.

Well in the lfs book (chap2.4) I followed every requirement: "A minimal system requires a partition of around 10 gigabytes (GB). This is enough to store all the source tarballs and compile the packages. However, if the LFS system is intended to be the primary Linux system, additional software will probably be installed which will require additional space. A 30 GB partition is a reasonable size to provide for growth."
Note that I also have a swap partition.

This is enough to store all the source tarballs and compile the packages..  That statement does not include the Testsuites.  For that, see Section 4.6
